# How to change first button's value by pressing another one

Tags: java, android, button, settings, flashlight

What I am seeking is to have button that has a x value and after pressing another button to change the value of the first. e.x first button value is, when pressed to open flashlight constantly, then I press the second button and now first's value button has changed, when pressed flashlight blinks!

Thanks in advance

```
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        // playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

    Change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // i want it to start blinking
            } else {
                //wait till opens to start blinking
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and on clicking again button change, everything to return to normal.

Comment: what kind of value do you want to change?

Comment: Some piece of code would it make easier to give an explanation :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what you really want.. can you explain a bit more?